# How to use the Fn traits (closures) in Rust function signatures?

Tags: rust

I want to write an `i32`-returning function that accepts a closure taking zero arguments, a closure taking one argument, and a closure taking two arguments, where all closure arguments are of type `i32` and every closure returns `f32`.

What is that function's signature going to look like?

I want to accept these via the `Fn` and `FnMut` traits. What does the signature look like? Is the use of features in the crate required? If so, which ones and why?

If known: what does it look like sugared? Desugared?

If known: what is likely to be changed in the future?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I want to write an `i32`-returning function that accepts a closure
>   taking zero arguments, a closure taking one argument, and a closure
>   taking two arguments, where all closure arguments are of type `i32` and
>   every closure returns `f32`.
>
> What is that function's signature going to look like?

It looks like this:

```
fn closures<F1, F2, F3>(mut f1: F1, mut f2: F2, mut f3: F3) -> i32
where
    F1: FnMut() -> f32,
    F2: FnMut(i32) -> f32,
    F3: FnMut(i32, i32) -> f32,
{
    (f1() + f2(10) + f3(20, 30)) as i32
}

fn main() {
    let x = closures(|| 0.1, |x| (2 * x) as f32, |x, y| (x + y) as f32);
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

You can use `Fn` instead of `FnMut` (and remove `mut` before `f1`, `f2` and `f3`) if you want to force the caller to pass closures which don't mutate their environment, but in general, I think, you would want to use `FnMut`.

This code uses unboxed closure sugar and overloaded calls. Without them, it would look like this:

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures, fn_traits)]

fn closures<F1, F2, F3>(mut f1: F1, mut f2: F2, mut f3: F3) -> i32
where
    F1: FnMut<(), Output = f32>,
    F2: FnMut<(i32,), Output = f32>,
    F3: FnMut<(i32, i32), Output = f32>,
{
    (f1.call_mut(()) + f2.call_mut((10,)) + f3.call_mut((20, 30))) as i32
}

fn main() {
    let x = closures(|| 0.1, |x| (2 * x) as f32, |x, y| (x + y) as f32);
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

The sugar is used to prettify closure type syntax, and the overloaded calls feature allows to omit explicit `call_*` methods.

#### Before Rust 1.0

> **Editor's note** This question was asked before Rust 1.0, and this section only applies to the changes that happened between then and 1.0.

As for what's going to change in future, then it is likely that closure construction syntax would be simplified (when current closures are dropped), so the `main()` bit will change from this:

```
fn main() {
    let x = closures(
        |&mut:| 0.1,
        |&mut: x: int| (2*x) as f32,
        |&mut: x: int, y: int| (x + y) as f32
    );
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

to look like this:

```
fn main() {
    let x = closures(
        || 0.1,
        |x| (2*x) as f32,
        |x, y| (x + y) as f32
    );
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

The actual type of the closure (`FnMut`, `Fn` or `FnOnce`) is going to be inferred.

There will also be other changes, like the `move` keyword for closures which are returned from functions (`move` affects variable capturing semantics). This is covered by [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0231-upvar-capture-inference.md) accepted RFC.

In general, unboxed closures are outlined in [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0114-closures.md) RFC. It is not updated, however, with new closures sugar syntax and with other subtle changes; it may be better to follow Rust [issue tracker](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues) to find out more on this. For example, a lot of issues with unboxed closures are aggregated in [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18101) bug.

Comment: Huh. I was looking through the RFCs trying to find info on the Fn traits and I guess I missed it because I was looking for 'traits' and not 'closures'. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, these things are called unboxed closures, you will find a lot on them if you look for this term.

Answer (score 11):

[`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html), [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html) and [`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html) are the three trait types that were introduced with unboxed closures. The difference between these traits, besides the name of their single method, is that the `self` parameter on these methods is passed differently:

- `Fn`: `&self` (by reference, can't mutate the closure's environment)
- `FnMut`: `&mut self` (by reference, can mutate the closure's environment)
- `FnOnce`: `self` (by value, consumes the closure, so the closure cannot be called more than once)

These traits have one type parameter, `Args`, which is a tuple type that represents the closure's parameters (or `()` if the closure takes no parameters). `FnOnce` has the associated type `Result`, which is the closure's return type. `Fn` is a subtrait of `FnMut`, and `FnMut` is a subtrait of `FnOnce`, which means that `Fn` and `FnMut` "inherit" `Result` from `FnOnce`. Unboxed closures automatically implement the applicable traits.

## Sugared form

### Closure taking zero arguments

```
fn foo<F: Fn() -> f32>(closure: F) -> i32 {
    0
}
```

### Closure taking one argument

```
fn foo<F: Fn(i32) -> f32>(closure: F) -> i32 {
    0
}
```

### Closure taking two arguments

```
fn foo<F: Fn(i32, i32) -> f32>(closure: F) -> i32 {
    0
}
```

## Using a `where` clause

Each of these can also use the `where` syntax:

```
fn foo<F>(closure: F) -> i32
where
    F: Fn() -> f32,
{
    0
}
```

See also:

- [What's the difference between `<T: Trait>` and `where T: Trait`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46793494/155423)

## Using the `impl trait` syntax:

```
fn foo_impl(closure: impl Fn() -> f32) -> i32 {
    0
}
```

See also:

- [What are the differences between an impl trait argument and generic function parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47514930/155423)
- [What does `impl` mean when used as the argument type or return type of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48545035/155423)
- [What makes `impl Trait` as an argument "universal" and as a return value "existential"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47929824/155423)

## Desugared versions

This format is unstable, and each of these examples requires using the feature gate `#![feature(unboxed_closures)]`. You can also use the `where` or `impl trait` syntax.

See also:

- [How do I implement the Fn trait for one struct for different types of arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38672235/155423)

### Closure taking zero arguments

```
fn foo<F: Fn<(), Output = f32>>(closure: F) -> i32 {
    0
}
```

### Closure taking one argument

```
fn foo<F: Fn<(i32,), Output = f32>>(closure: F) -> i32 {
    0
}
```

### Closure taking two arguments

```
fn foo<F: Fn<(i32, i32), Output = f32>>(closure: F) -> i32 {
    0
}
```

## Old "boxed" closures

"Boxed" closures existed at the time this question was asked, but they were [removed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/20578) before Rust 1.0.

[This metabug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18101) tracked the development of unboxed closures.