# How do I implement the Fn trait for one struct for different types of arguments?

Tags: operator-overloading, rust, function-call-operator

I have a simple classifier:

```
struct Clf {
    x: f64,
}
```

The classifier returns 0 if the observed value is smaller than `x` and 1 if bigger than `x`.

I want to implement the call operator for this classifier. However, the function should be able to take either a float or a vector as arguments. In case of a vector, the output is a vector of 0 or 1 which has the same size as the input vector:

```
let c = Clf { x: 0 };
let v = vec![-1, 0.5, 1];
println!("{}", c(0.5));   // prints 1
println!("{}", c(v));     // prints [0, 1, 1]
```

How can I write implementation of `Fn` in this case?

```
impl Fn for Clf {
    extern "rust-call" fn call(/*...*/) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The short answer is: You can't. At least it won't work the way you want. I think the best way to show that is to walk through and see what happens, but the general idea is that Rust doesn't support function overloading.

For this example, we will be implementing `FnOnce`, because `Fn` requires `FnMut` which requires `FnOnce`. So, if we were to get this all sorted, we could do it for the other function traits.

First, this is unstable, so we need some feature flags

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures, fn_traits)]
```

Then, let's do the `impl` for taking an `f64`:

```
impl FnOnce<(f64,)> for Clf {
    type Output = i32;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: (f64,)) -> i32 {
        if args.0 > self.x {
            1
        } else {
            0
        }
    }
}
```

The arguments to the `Fn` family of traits are supplied via a tuple, so that's the `(f64,)` syntax; it's a tuple with just one element.

This is all well and good, and we can now do `c(0.5)`, although it will consume `c` until we implement the other traits.

Now let's do the same thing for `Vec`s:

```
impl FnOnce<(Vec<f64>,)> for Clf {
    type Output = Vec<i32>;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: (Vec<f64>,)) -> Vec<i32> {
        args.0
            .iter()
            .map(|&f| if f > self.x { 1 } else { 0 })
            .collect()
    }
}
```

Before [Rust 1.33 nightly](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/55986), you cannot directly call `c(v)` or even `c(0.5)` (which worked before); we'd get an error about the type of the function not being known. Basically, these versions of Rust didn't support function overloading. But we can still call the functions using [fully qualified syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name), where `c(0.5)` becomes `FnOnce::call_once(c, (0.5,))`.

---

Not knowing your bigger picture, I would want to solve this simply by giving `Clf` two functions like so:

```
impl Clf {
    fn classify(&self, val: f64) -> u32 {
        if val > self.x {
            1
        } else {
            0
        }
    }

    fn classify_vec(&self, vals: Vec<f64>) -> Vec<u32> {
        vals.into_iter().map(|v| self.classify(v)).collect()
    }
}
```

Then your usage example becomes

```
let c = Clf { x: 0 };
let v = vec![-1, 0.5, 1];
println!("{}", c.classify(0.5));   // prints 1
println!("{}", c.classify_vec(v)); // prints [0, 1, 1]
```

I would actually want to make the second function `classify_slice` and take `&[f64]` to be a bit more general, then you could still use it with `Vec`s by referencing them: `c.classify_slice(&v)`.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that this is old (historical) syntax nowadays?

Answer (score 12):

This is indeed possible, but you need a new trait and a ton of mess.

If you start with the abstraction

```
enum VecOrScalar<T> {
    Scalar(T),
    Vector(Vec<T>),
}

use VecOrScalar::*;
```

You want a way to use the type transformations

```
T      (hidden) -> VecOrScalar<T> -> T      (known)
Vec<T> (hidden) -> VecOrScalar<T> -> Vec<T> (known)
```

because then you can take a "hidden" type `T`, wrap it in a `VecOrScalar` and extract the real type `T` with a `match`.

You also want

```
T      (known) -> bool      = T::Output
Vec<T> (known) -> Vec<bool> = Vec<T>::Output
```

but without higher-kinded-types, this is a bit tricky. Instead, you can do

```
T      (known) -> VecOrScalar<T> -> T::Output
Vec<T> (known) -> VecOrScalar<T> -> Vec<T>::Output
```

if you allow for a branch that can panic.

The trait will thus be

```
trait FromVecOrScalar<T> {
    type Output;

    fn put(self) -> VecOrScalar<T>;

    fn get(out: VecOrScalar<bool>) -> Self::Output;
}
```

with implementations

```
impl<T> FromVecOrScalar<T> for T {
    type Output = bool;

    fn put(self) -> VecOrScalar<T> {
        Scalar(self)
    }

    fn get(out: VecOrScalar<bool>) -> Self::Output {
        match out {
            Scalar(val) => val,
            Vector(_) => panic!("Wrong output type!"),
        }
    }
}
```

```
impl<T> FromVecOrScalar<T> for Vec<T> {
    type Output = Vec<bool>;

    fn put(self) -> VecOrScalar<T> {
        Vector(self)
    }

    fn get(out: VecOrScalar<bool>) -> Self::Output {
        match out {
            Vector(val) => val,
            Scalar(_) => panic!("Wrong output type!"),
        }
    }
}
```

Your type

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Clf {
    x: f64,
}
```

will first implement the two branches:

```
impl Clf {
    fn calc_scalar(self, f: f64) -> bool {
        f > self.x
    }

    fn calc_vector(self, v: Vec<f64>) -> Vec<bool> {
        v.into_iter().map(|x| self.calc_scalar(x)).collect()
    }
}
```

Then it will dispatch by implementing `FnOnce` for `T: FromVecOrScalar<f64>`

```
impl<T> FnOnce<(T,)> for Clf
where
    T: FromVecOrScalar<f64>,
{
```

with types

```
    type Output = T::Output;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, (arg,): (T,)) -> T::Output {
```

The dispatch first boxes the private type up, so you can extract it with the `enum`, and then `T::get`s the result, to hide it again.

```
        match arg.put() {
            Scalar(scalar) => T::get(Scalar(self.calc_scalar(scalar))),
            Vector(vector) => T::get(Vector(self.calc_vector(vector))),
        }
    }
}
```

Then, success:

```
fn main() {
    let c = Clf { x: 0.0 };
    let v = vec![-1.0, 0.5, 1.0];
    println!("{}", c(0.5f64));
    println!("{:?}", c(v));
}
```

Since the compiler can see through all of this malarky, it actually compiles away to basically the same assembly as a direct call to the `calc_` methods.

That's not to say it's nice to write. Overloading like this is a pain, fragile and most certainly A Bad Idea™. Don't do it, though it's fine to know that you can.

Answer (score 5):

You can't (but read until the end of the answer).

First of all, implementing the `Fn*` family of traits explicitly is unstable and subject to change at any time, so it'd be a bad idea to depend on that.

Secondly, and more importantly, the Rust compiler before [Rust 1.33 nightly](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/55986) just *will not* let you call a value that has `Fn*` implementations for different argument types.  It just can't work out what you want it to do, since there's normally no way for it to happen.  The only way around that is fully specifying the trait you wanted to call, but at that point, you've lost any possible ergonomic benefit of this approach.

Just define and implement your own trait instead of trying to use the `Fn*` traits.  I took some liberties with the question to avoid/fix questionable aspects.

```
struct Clf {
    x: f64,
}

trait ClfExt<T: ?Sized> {
    type Result;
    fn classify(&self, arg: &T) -> Self::Result;
}

impl ClfExt<f64> for Clf {
    type Result = bool;
    fn classify(&self, arg: &f64) -> Self::Result {
        *arg > self.x
    }
}

impl ClfExt<[f64]> for Clf {
    type Result = Vec<bool>;
    fn classify(&self, arg: &[f64]) -> Self::Result {
        arg.iter().map(|v| self.classify(v)).collect()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c = Clf { x: 0.0 };
    let v = vec![-1.0, 0.5, 1.0];
    println!("{}", c.classify(&0.5f64));
    println!("{:?}", c.classify(&v[..]));
}
```

#### How to use the `Fn*` traits

I've included this for the sake of completeness; *do not actually do this.*  Not only is it unsupported, it's *damn* ugly.

```
#![feature(fn_traits, unboxed_closures)]

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Clf {
    x: f64,
}

impl FnOnce<(f64,)> for Clf {
    type Output = bool;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: (f64,)) -> Self::Output {
        args.0 > self.x
    }
}

impl<'a> FnOnce<(&'a [f64],)> for Clf {
    type Output = Vec<bool>;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: (&'a [f64],)) -> Self::Output {
        args.0
            .iter()
            .cloned()
            .map(|v| FnOnce::call_once(self, (v,)))
            .collect()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c = Clf { x: 0.0 };
    let v = vec![-1.0, 0.5, 1.0];

    // Before 1.33 nightly
    println!("{}", FnOnce::call_once(c, (0.5f64,)));
    println!("{:?}", FnOnce::call_once(c, (&v[..],)));

    // After
    println!("{}", c(0.5f64));
    println!("{:?}", c(&v[..]));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do using nightly and unstable features:

```rust
#![feature(fn_traits, unboxed_closures)]
struct Clf {
    x: f64,
}

impl FnOnce<(f64,)> for Clf {
    type Output = i32;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: (f64,)) -> i32 {
        if args.0 > self.x {
            1
        } else {
            0
        }
    }
}

impl FnOnce<(Vec<f64>,)> for Clf {
    type Output = Vec<i32>;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: (Vec<f64>,)) -> Vec<i32> {
        args.0
            .iter()
            .map(|&f| if f > self.x { 1 } else { 0 })
            .collect()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c = Clf { x: 0.0 };
    let v = vec![-1.0, 0.5, 1.0];
    println!("{:?}", c(0.5));

    let c = Clf { x: 0.0 };
    println!("{:?}", c(v));
}
```

Comment: This answer is seemingly already provided [by an existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38672502/155423). Please thoroughly read *all* existing answers before providing new ones. Clearly distinguish what makes your answer distinct from existing ones if it truly is different.