# How do I solve the error "the precise format of `Fn`-family traits' type parameters is subject to change"?

Tags: rust, traits

I have written a problem solver in Rust which as a subroutine needs to make calls to a function which is given as a black box (essentially I would like to give an argument of type `Fn(f64) -> f64`).

Essentially I have a function defined as `fn solve<F>(f: F) where F : Fn(f64) -> f64 { ... }` which means that I can call `solve` like this:
`solve(|x| x);`

What I would like to do is to pass a more complex function to the solver, i.e. a function which depends on multiple parameters etc.

I would like to be able to pass a struct with a suitable trait implementation to the solver. I tried the following:

```
struct Test;
impl Fn<(f64,)> for Test {}
```

This yield the following error:

```
error: the precise format of `Fn`-family traits' type parameters is subject to change. Use parenthetical notation (Fn(Foo, Bar) -> Baz) instead (see issue #29625)
```

I would also like to add a trait which includes the `Fn` trait (which I don't know how to define, unfortunately). Is that possible as well?

Edit:
Just to clarify: I have been developing in C++ for quite a while, the C++ solution would be to overload the `operator()(args)`. In that case I could use a `struct` or `class` like a function. I would like to be able to

1. Pass both functions and structs to the solver as arguments.
2. Have an easy way to call the functions. Calling `obj.method(args)` is more complicated than `obj(args)` (in C++). But it seems that this behavior is not achievable currently.

Comment: [One question per question, please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The direct answer is to do exactly as the error message says:

> Use parenthetical notation instead

That is, instead of `Fn<(A, B)>`, use `Fn(A, B)`

The *real problem* is that you are [not allowed to implement the `Fn*` family of traits yourself in stable Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38672235/155423).

The *real question* you are asking is harder to be sure of because you haven't provided a [MCVE](/help/mcve), so we are reduced to guessing. I'd say you should flip it around the other way; create a new trait, implement it for closures and your type:

```
trait Solve {
    type Output;
    fn solve(&mut self) -> Self::Output;
}

impl<F, T> Solve for F
where
    F: FnMut() -> T,
{
    type Output = T;

    fn solve(&mut self) -> Self::Output {
        (self)()
    }
}

struct Test;
impl Solve for Test {
    // interesting things
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited the question in order to clarify things.