# Can I specify the type for iterators based on closures?

Tags: rust, types, closures

I wrote a function to iterate over neighbors of cells in a 2d grid:

```rust
pub fn neighbours(
    (width, height): (usize, usize),
    (x, y): (usize, usize),
) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize)> {
    [(-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)]
        .iter()
        .map(move |(dx, dy)| (x as i64 + dx, y as i64 + dy))
        .filter(move |&(nx, ny)| 0 <= ny && ny < height as i64 && 0 <= nx && nx < width as i64)
        .map(|(nx, ny)| (nx as usize, ny as usize))
}
```

Note that it returns an `impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize)>`.

If I understand correctly, returning an `impl` would result in slower code, calling function pointers instead of compiling things down to simple loops. Right?

So wanting to specify a more exact type, I replaced the type with `()` to see what type the compiler infers, and it infers

```rust
std::iter::Map<std::iter::Filter<std::iter::Map<std::slice::Iter<'l, (i64, i64)>, _>, _>, _>
```

Where the `_`s stand for closures which I don't know how to specify their types.

I tried to extract the closures to structs with `Fn` traits but couldn't make that work and also [IIUC implementing `Fn` traits is an unstable feature and I shouldn't use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38672581/40916)"

Comment: `impl` is just sintactic sugar iirc. It will actually use of generics and compile for each type you use the function (which is what you want to do manually). But lets see if someone corroborates this

Comment: From [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/ch10-02-traits.html#returning-types-that-implement-traits): *"The impl Trait syntax lets you concisely specify that a function returns some type that implements the Iterator trait without needing to write out a very long type."*. It's not dynamic, you can't for example have a branch and return two different types. As @Netwave said, it's a facility to write the type when you can't because it's too long or involves closures

Comment: Isn't `Iterator` the most appropriate return type, though? I think that if one were to export the full internal type, it would leak a lot of information about the implementation and would need to be changed every time the implementation changes, too. I'm not familiar enough with the compiled representation of these constructs but I would have assumed that changing the type annotation doesn't change the generated code in this case either.

Comment: @DenysSéguret oh nice I didn't realize that it is not dynamic. So I guess if anyone writes it as an answer I could accept it :)

Comment: You're probably confusing `impl` (as said above, just generics) with `dyn`. The latter means a ["trait object"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.2.0/book/trait-objects.html) being returned, which would erase any knowledge of the concrete type, and would indeed incur some runtime cost because, in order to call any method on those objects, the vtable would have to be looked up first.

Comment: @Netwave While it's true that `impl` is not dynamic, and there is no performance loss, it is **not** true that `impl` (in return position) is just syntactic sugar. One cannot syntactically transform a function that returns `impl Trait` into one that uses named generics (which is whay "syntactic sugar" would imply). `impl Trait` was introduced to support efficient returning of futures, which was crucial for async/await and could not be achieved with generics as they were at the time.

Comment: @Netwave In particular, the "obvious" transformation of `fn foo() {...} -> impl Bar` into `fn foo<T: Bar>() -> T {...}` doesn't compile no matter what's in `...` because the caller gets to choose the `T`. The same transformation works with `impl` in argument position, which *can* be considered syntactic sugar (and which is why many opposed it). In type theory, `impl Trait` in return position is called _existentially-quantified type_, whereas regular generics are universally-qualified types. See https://varkor.github.io/blog/2018/07/03/existential-types-in-rust.html for an extended discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I understand correctly, returning an `impl` would result in slower code, calling function pointers instead of compiling things down to simple loops. Right?

Nope. Returning `impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize)>` is exactly the same, codegen-wise, as returning `Map<Filter<Map<...>>>`.¹ The difference is twofold:

- Changing the return type of `neighbours` does not require changing its signature, so `impl Iterator` is forward-compatible with changes to its return type.
- `impl Iterator` won't unify with other opaque `impl Iterator` types, even if they happen to have the same underlying type. (In simple terms: the compiler won't allow you to make a `Vec` of `impl Iterator`s from different sources, even if all those opaque types are the same concrete type.)

Neither of these differences has any influence on code generation or the compiler's ability to inline anything, so go ahead and use `impl Iterator`.

There is one case where you must still use indirect dispatch (`dyn Iterator`): when the function `neighbours` is itself part of a trait, the `impl Trait` syntax is not yet available (as of 1.59). The best way to solve this at the moment is to return `Box<dyn Iterator>`. (Note, however, that doesn't mean *every* call will be dynamically dispatched; the call to `.next()` will be, but everything "inside" that still uses easily-optimized static dispatch.)

### Related questions

- [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/3650362)
- [How do I return an instance of a trait from a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30661046/3650362)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39490692/3650362 (when the method is part of a trait)

---

¹ Note that in order to actually *return* `Map<Filter<Map<...>>>`, you would still have to use `impl Trait` to represent the closures, since they have anonymous types.