# What's the difference between `<T: Trait>` and `where T: Trait`?

Tags: rust, traits

In [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html) for the `Send` trait, I see both

```
impl<T> Send for LinkedList<T> 
where
    T: Send,
```

and

```
impl<T: Send> Send for LinkedList<T>
```

What is the difference between these two syntaxes, and how would it impact my code if I was writing `impl` declarations for my own trait?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Trait bounds defined inside a `where` clause are a superset of the trait bounds declared inline. The inline style existed before the `where` clause; the `where` clause  was [introduced in RFC 135](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0135-where.md):

> Add `where` clauses, which provide a more expressive means of
> specifying trait parameter bounds. [...] The existing bounds notation
> would remain as syntactic sugar for `where` clauses.

> Here is a list of limitations with the current bounds syntax that are
> overcome with the where syntax:
>
> - **It cannot express bounds on anything other than type parameters.** Therefore, if you have a function generic in `T`, you can write
>   `T:MyTrait` to declare that `T` must implement `MyTrait`, but you can't
>   write `Option<T> : MyTrait` or `(int, T) : MyTrait`. These forms are less
>   commonly required but still important.
> - **It does not work well with associated types.** This is because there is no space to specify the value of an associated type. Other
>   languages use where clauses (or something analogous) for this purpose.
> - **It's just plain hard to read.** Experience has shown that as the number of bounds grows, the current syntax becomes hard to read and
>   format.

Since then you can also use *higher-ranked trait bounds* (`for <'a> ...`) in a `where` clause:

```
fn foo<T, U>()
where
    // higher-ranked trait bounds
    for<'a> T: SomethingElse<'a>,
    // Bound not directly on the generic type
    i32: From<U>,
    T: Iterator,
    // Bound on an associated type
    T::Item: Clone,
    // Just really long
    U: ReallyLong + AnotherReallyLong + WowReallyLong,
{}
```

If your needs can be met by the inline trait bounds, then there is no impact on your code. If you need the extra powers that only `where` enables, then you need to use `where`.

See also:

- [What are the differences between an impl trait argument and generic function parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47514930/155423)

---

My personal style is to *always* use the `where` form. Having a single shape that is also easier to `git diff` when adding new bounds is worth the extra line of code for me.

Comment: TBH it's one of those instances where I long for the Zen of Python :) Also, historically there have been minor discrepancies, I remember `?Sized` could only be used in a `where` clause for a while.

Comment: @MatthieuM. it was the other way around — `?Sized` only worked inline. I remember because I also prefer a single style (using a `where`) but it didn't work for `?Sized`...

Answer (score 1):

The [`where` clause documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/generics/where.html) now includes the example:

> When specifying generic types and bounds separately is clearer:

```
impl <A: TraitB + TraitC, D: TraitE + TraitF> MyTrait<A, D> for YourType {}

// Expressing bounds with a `where` clause
impl <A, D> MyTrait<A, D> for YourType where
    A: TraitB + TraitC,
    D: TraitE + TraitF {}
```

[shepmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155423/shepmaster) mentions:

> My personal style is to always use the where form.
> Having a single shape that is also easier to `git diff` when adding new bounds is worth the extra line of code for me.

I agree, considering Git 2.23 (Q3 2019) will add rust to its  funcname and words
boundaries.

See [commit 33be7b3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33be7b38c23fbbaf75197f6150323e0d4c84bf12) (30 May 2019) by [Johannes Sixt (`j6t`)](https://github.com/j6t).
See [commit d74e786](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d74e78602e3d562f5db64d553d4be21c201ef7b3) (16 May 2019) by [Marc-André Lureau (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a41dad4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a41dad4330c8291893b5c5b013457499855ec9b5), 21 Jun 2019)</sup>

> ### userdiff: add built-in pattern for rust
>
> This adds `xfuncname` and `word_regex` patterns for Rust, a quite popular programming language.
> It also includes test cases for the `xfuncname` regex ([t4018](https://github.com/git/git/tree/d74e78602e3d562f5db64d553d4be21c201ef7b3/t/t4018)) and updated documentation.