# What are the differences between an impl trait argument and generic function parameter?

Tags: rust

[`impl Trait`s can be used as function arguments](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/trait-system/impl-trait-for-returning-complex-types-with-ease.html). Are there differences between this and a generic function with a trait constraint?

```
trait Foo {}

fn func1(_: impl Foo) {}

fn func2<T: Foo>(_: T) {}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`impl Trait`s as function arguments are desugared to an anonymous generic parameter. See the [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1951-expand-impl-trait.md#the-proposal-in-a-nutshell), which says:

> Expand `impl Trait` to allow use in arguments, where it behaves like an anonymous generic parameter.

There's also an example in the RFC:

```
// These two are equivalent
fn map<U>(self, f: impl FnOnce(T) -> U) -> Option<U>
fn map<U, F>(self, f: F) -> Option<U> where F: FnOnce(T) -> U
```

However, one difference is that `impl Trait` arguments cannot have their types explicitly specified:

```
fn foo<T: Trait>(t: T)
fn bar(t: impl Trait)

foo::<u32>(0) // this is allowed
bar::<u32>(0) // this is not
```

The [Motivation for expanding to argument position](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1951-expand-impl-trait.md#motivation-for-expanding-to-argument-position) section explains why additional syntax was added for an existing feature. In short, it's for having similar syntax as `impl` traits in function return position, which improves learnability, and to improve ergonomics.

Comment: Hm, thanks. I did not read the RFC; I only saw the link to the github issue from "this week in Rust".

Comment: @Boiethios RFCs, even merged RFCs, aren't always accurate to the current version of Rust -- they may be not-yet-implemented, implemented-with-changes, or superseded -- so it's still a fair question. However, in this case the RFC is accurate.

Comment: (When changes have been made since the RFC was merged, you'd hope to find that in the tracking issue for the RFC.)

Answer (score 9):

Both produce identical assembly, at least with the following simple test case:

```
trait Foo {}

struct Bar;

impl Foo for Bar {}

fn func1(_: impl Foo) {}

fn func2<T: Foo>(_: T) {}

fn main() {
    let x = Bar;

    let y = func1(x); // or func2(x);
}
```