# Why is `impl` needed when passing traits as function parameters?

Tags: syntax, rust, traits

In the following example of passing a trait as a parameter, what's the need of sending `impl` in the function signature?

I understand that traits are more generic types and not concrete types, but since the Rust compiler doesn't allow sharing names across structs and traits, why is there a need to provide `impl` in the function signature to represent the type?

```rust
pub fn notify(item: impl Summary) {
    println!("Breaking news! {}", item.summarize());
}
```

The documentation mentions that the above signature is just syntactic sugar for the below signature. Wouldn't it make sense to use `trait Summary` instead of `impl Summary` as `impl` can also be used to define methods on structs?

```rust
pub fn notify<T: Summary>(item: T) {
    println!("Breaking news! {}", item.summarize());
}
```

Is there any hidden concept around it that I'm missing?

Comment: *I understand traits are more generic types and not concrete types* — the trait's name is **both** a type and a trait. See [What does “dyn” mean in a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50650070/155423)

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [What does `impl` mean when used as the argument type or return type of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48545035/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Are you just asking why it's `impl Foo` rather than `trait Foo`? The syntax `impl Foo` can be read as "something that *implements* `Foo`", so the syntax makes perfect sense.

Comment: Yes @mcarton . It's all about the syntax. In other languages like go and java, where interface is also a type, you name the type of the parameter as `interface` . I expected similar thing from rustc to have `f: trait Foo` rather than `f: impl Foo` or simply `f: Foo` as the duplicate types are not anyways allowed by compiler.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Contrary to languages such as Go or Java, Rust allows for both static and dynamic dispatch, and some syntax was required to let programmers choose between the two.

As dynamic dispatch must work on objects which might not be `Sized`, you need a reference to use it. That is, you would use `&dyn Trait` or `Box<dyn Trait>` (note: for historical reasons, the `dyn` keyword is not required, but modern Rust uses it). In C++, dynamic dispatch also requires a reference or pointer.

Static dispatch is not something Go or Java have. In C++, it works with templates and duck-typing. In Rust, it works with generics and traits, and its original syntax was:

```rust
fn some_function<T: Trait>(foo: T) { … }
```

Later, the following syntax was added to the language:

```
fn some_function(foo: impl Trait) { … }
```

which is equivalent to the above.

This syntax was originally invented to be used in return types, where there is no generic equivalent:

```
fn some_function() -> impl Trait { … }
```

This means that `some_function` can return any single type that implements `Trait`, but this type must be known at compile time. This has some performance benefits over returning `Box<Trait>` for example. In C++, the closest equivalent would be returning `auto` or `decltype(auto)`.

The syntax in parameter position was added for symmetry.

You might wonder why not simply make the generics implicit and have:

```
fn some_function(foo: Trait) { … }
```

But this would be slightly confusing. `Trait` by itself is not sized, and therefore cannot be used as a parameter, unless they are generic. This would make traits stand out in the realm of unsized types. For example, if `(foo: Trait)` would work, you might wonder why `(foo: str)` doesn't, but what would that one mean? There is also other problems with making generics implicit, for example, generics in traits make the trait non-object-safe.

---

Later, Rust will likely extend those existential types and allow this at a module level:

```rust
type Foo = impl Bar;
```

(which is currently allowed on nightly, guarded by the `type_alias_impl_trait` feature)

---

Finally, you are asking why the syntax is `impl Foo`, rather than `trait Foo`. This reads well as "a type that implements Foo". The [original RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/105/files) doesn't discuss alternative syntaxes much. [Another RFC discusses the syntax more](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1951-expand-impl-trait.md), in particular whether the syntax should have been `any Foo` in parameter position, and `some Foo` in return position. The syntax `trait Foo` was never considered as far as I am aware.

Comment: Very clear explanation, particularly no-size nature of traits if mixed with sized concrete types could create confusion. I think this `type Foo = impl Bar;` would make definite sense.
Thanks a lot