# How to pass a Future as a function argument?

Tags: rust, future, rust-tokio, tokio-postgres

I am used to Scala's `Future` type where you wrap whatever object you're returning in `Future[..]` to designate it as such.

My Rust function `hello` returns `Query` and I don't seem able to pass that result as an argument with type `Future<Output = Query>`. Why not and how should I type this better?

The failure occurs when I try to pass the future as an argument:

```rust
use std::future::Future;

struct Person;
struct DatabaseError;

type Query = Result<Vec<Person>, DatabaseError>;

async fn hello_future(future: &dyn Future<Output = Query>) -> bool {
    future.await.is_ok()
}

async fn hello() -> Query {
    unimplemented!()
}

async fn example() {
    let f = hello();
    hello_future(&f);
}

fn main() {}
```

Which fails to compile with the error:

```
error[E0277]: `&dyn Future<Output = Result<Vec<Person>, DatabaseError>>` is not a future
 --> src/main.rs:9:5
  |
9 |     future.await.is_ok()
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ `&dyn Future<Output = Result<Vec<Person>, DatabaseError>>` is not a future
  |
  = help: the trait `Future` is not implemented for `&dyn Future<Output = Result<Vec<Person>, DatabaseError>>`
  = note: required by `poll`
```

Comment: keep in mind I'm connecting over local host, so even if I paste each and every character, there's still the entire database missing. I'd just return dummy data, but then the interaction with `tokio_postgres` would be lost, hence my post the way it is... Is that reasonable?

Comment: *there's still the entire database missing* — that's true, but that is a runtime requirement. You have a compilation error, which is far before even attempting to run the program, much less connect to the database.

Comment: ah, yeah makes sense since compile error running end2end not needed

Comment: Another route: why did you want to pass the _future_ to the function, instead of just passing in `Query`? The first thing you do is `.await` it. Even if you wanted to pass the future, does `(future: impl Future<Output = Query>)` work in your real case?

Comment: now I'm even more confused, yes that `impl` does work!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`async` functions desugar to returning an opaque value that implements the `Future` trait. This means that you can accept a generic type that implements that trait. The most succinct syntax is `impl Trait`, but you could also introduce a named generic parameter:

```rust
async fn hello_future(future: impl Future<Output = Query>) -> bool {
    future.await.is_ok()
}

async fn example() {
    let f = hello();
    hello_future(f);
}
```

See also:

- [Is it possible to await a &dyn Future?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67373797/155423)
- [What is the concrete type of a future returned from `async fn`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58762210/155423)
- [Why is `impl` needed when passing traits as function parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57562632/155423)
- [What does `impl` mean when used as the argument type or return type of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48545035/155423)
- [How to accept an async function as an argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60717746/155423)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Query>>>` as parameter:

```
async fn hello_future(future: Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Query>>>) -> bool {
    future.await.is_ok()
}
...
async fn example() {
    let f: impl Future<Output = Result<Vec<Person>, DatabaseError>> = hello();
    hello_future(Box::pin(f));
}
```

The difference is that `impl Future` is compile-time dispatch. Compiler generates executable code for each per-type instantiation of `hello_future`. And `Pin<Box<...>>` is runtime dispatch. Only one copy of the executable binary code for `hello_future` is generated.