# Difference between specifying return type with trait bounds vs. impl

Tags: rust

I'm going through the 2018 Rust Book and started learning about the various forms of generic syntax with traits. I tried each of the different ways of specifying traits using their example `largest` function, but got unexpected results.

```rust
use std::cmp::PartialOrd;

fn main() {
    let i = vec![11, 7, 19, 3, -5];
    let f = vec![9.2, 3.4, 1.0, -5.678, 0.0];
    let c = vec!['*', 'h', '!', '~', 'Q'];

    println!("{}", largest_bound(&i));
    println!("{}", largest_where(&f));
    println!("{}", largest_impl(&c));
}

fn largest_bound<T: PartialOrd + Copy>(list: &[T]) -> T {
    let mut largest = list[0];
    for &item in list {
        if item > largest {
            largest = item;
        }
    }

    largest
}

fn largest_where<T:>(list: &[T]) -> T
    where T: PartialOrd + Copy
{
    // same body
}

fn largest_impl(list: &[(impl PartialOrd + Copy)]) -> impl PartialOrd + Copy {
    // same body
}
```

`largest_bound` and `largest_where` work, but `largest_impl` fails with the following error:

```
error[E0277]: `impl PartialOrd+Copy` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
  --> src\main.rs:10:20
   |
10 |     println!("{}", largest_impl(&i));
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `impl PartialOrd+Copy` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
   |
   = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `impl PartialOrd+Copy`
   = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args_nl` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

For this code to work, I have to specify the `Display` trait in the signature:

```rust
use std::fmt::Display;
// ...
fn largest_impl(list: &[(impl PartialOrd + Copy + Display)]) -> impl PartialOrd + Copy + Display { //... }
```

What does specifying a return type with `impl` do differently so that I have to specify `Display` for it, whereas using other trait syntax doesn't require me to specify it?

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48545035/11898061) about `impl` syntax, but I don't see how the trait bound/where syntax is different in this regard:

> Here, [`impl`] is used in return position to say "the type returned will implement this trait, and that's all I'm telling you"

How does Rust derive more information from trait bounds/where clauses?

Comment: @vallentin I've viewed that question, with the key takeaway being that `impl` syntax says "the type returned will implement this trait, and that's all I'm telling you". But isn't that what the corresponding trait bound/where syntax does too? I don't see what more information is given there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key difference is that in `largest_bound` and `largest_where`, the parameter slice type and return type are defined to be the same since they use the same generic parameter `T`. However, in `largest_impl` the parameter slice type and return type can be different since there's nothing linking them together.

Even if the body of the function returns the same type as the parameter, that is an *implementation detail* that doesn't leak into the surrounding code. As written, the function is allowed to return any type that satisfies the constraints, and the surrounding code must deal with that.

So when trying to display the contents, the compiler knows that the return type is `i32`, `f64`, or `char` respectively, which the compiler knows all implement `Display`. However, since the return type of `largest_impl` can be *anything* that implements `PartialOrd + Copy`, it doesn't necessarily implement `Display` so you can't print it.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Hadn't put it together that the generic syntax links the argument and return type whereas the `impl` example does not. Thanks!