# Return impl and VS return generic type using where trait having different compiler response

Tags: rust, actix-web

Compiler having different behavior for using either of `return impl Responder` and `return T where T:Responder`

As mention here in [What does `impl` mean when used as the argument type or return type of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48545035/what-does-impl-mean-when-used-as-the-argument-type-or-return-type-of-a-functio) says that it just a syntax matter which having same purpose

```rust
use actix_web::Responder;

pub fn  get_user<T>() ->T
where T:Responder{

    "from User"
}
pub fn  get_user2()->impl Responder{

    "from User 2"
}
```

Why is this happening?

[image: compiler response]

===

[image: compiler response]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: thanks @cafce25, im sorry but i still feel bit bias for `function will produce some type T that implements something` this for return impl, but this sentence also true for `where T:something`

mind to elaborate a bit for my case?

Comment: No `T` is a type the caller selected and you have to provide a type of that type `impl Trait` is just any type you the calle can pick implementing `Trait`

Comment: hi @cafce25 i got some bit understanding, if using impl means something `that only implement` that trait, (existential). if using generic means anything that `atleast implement` that trait (universal). (?)