# How to return `impl Display` from a function

Tags: rust, io, traits

I'm struggling to understand how to properly implement alternative displays or traits of any kind for a struct.

```rust
struct Fraction {
  numerator: u32,
  denominator: u32
}

impl Fraction {
  fn unicode(&self) -> impl Display {
   // should I use named function or Closure?
   // Where does f come from?
   // can I re-use self?
   // How can I implement a trait that has multiple required functions or `type Output =`?
    fn fmt(&self, f: std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
       write!("{}⁄{}", self.numerator, self.denominator)
    } // <- this returns `()`
  }
}
```

This doesn't work, because `fn fmt` - as a function definition - doesn't return anything. Using an unnamed closure:

```rust
impl Fraction {
  fn unicode(&self) -> impl Display {
   // should I use named function or Closure?
   // Where does f come from?
   // can I re-use self?
   // How can I implement a trait that has multiple required functions or `type Output =`?
    |s: &Self, f: std::fmt::Formatter| -> std::fmt::Result {
       write!("{}⁄{}", self.numerator, self.denominator)
    } // <- this returns `()`
  }
}

// somewhere else:
impl Display for Fraction {
  fn fmt(&self, f: std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
    write!("{}/{}", self.numerator, self.denominator)
    //        ^-- ASCII '/'
  }
}
```

says:

```rust
error[E0277]: `{closure@src/fraction/generic_fraction.rs:422:9: 422:57}` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
   --> src/fraction/generic_fraction.rs:418:39
    |
418 |     fn display_mixed<'a>(&'a self) -> impl 'a + fmt::Display 
    |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `{closure@src/fraction/generic_fraction.rs:422:9: 422:57}` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
    |
    = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for closure `{closure@src/fraction/generic_fraction.rs:422:9: 422:57}`
    = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
```

similar questions:

- [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27535594/14681457)
- [What does `impl` mean when used as the argument type or return type of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48545113/14681457)

As opposed to returning an iterator (most docs I've found are about that), I'm trying to implement my trait in the function block. Hencewhy I couldn't find documentation. Maybe this is the wrong way of doing it/thinking about it?

Comment: There is no such thing as a bare trait object, you always need a struct that implements some trait. You'd want to do something along the lines as what [`Path::display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.display) does, possibly with the `struct Display` defined within `fn unicode`.

Comment: So if I have a struct that already implements that trait, I need to create like a wrapper struct? like `struct unicode(Fraction)`? and then impl Display for that and then return it in the `-> impl Display`? I

Comment: Yes, that's the way.

Comment: It kind of seems like you want `fn unicode(&self) -> impl Display { self }`?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that it's an *alternative* Display. e.g. I already have *Display* implemented for `Self` There is nightly [formatterfn](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/fmt/struct.FormatterFn.html#) that would make this possible though, but it's nightly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @cafce25 points out in the comments, you must return *something* that implements the trait, which in Rust means you need to have an instance of a type that implements the trait. But you can still "hide" this from the signature and the exported types, for example by declaring the type within the function:

```rust
fn foo() -> impl std::fmt::Display {
    struct Example;
    impl std::fmt::Display for Example {
        fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
            write!(f, "hi")
        }
    }
    Example
}

fn main() {
    let d = foo();
    println!("{d}"); // prints "hi"
}
```

The returned instance must carry enough data with it that its `Display` implementation can actually function. In the `Example` above, there is no data (`Example` is actually a [ZST](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html#zero-sized-types-zsts)), because the `fmt` implementation simply writes a constant string to the formatter.

More realistically though, you will need some data for the implementation, e.g. for your `Fraction`:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Fraction {
    numerator: u32,
    denominator: u32
}

impl Fraction {
    fn unicode(&self) -> impl std::fmt::Display {
        struct FractionAsUnicode(Fraction);
        impl std::fmt::Display for FractionAsUnicode {
            fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
                write!(f, "{}⁄{}", self.0.numerator, self.0.denominator)
            }
        }
        FractionAsUnicode(self.clone())
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid the clone and only capture the original fraction by shared reference (because the resulting object only needs to exist for the duration of a print call), you can do this instead:

```rust
fn unicode(&self) -> impl std::fmt::Display + '_ {
    struct FractionAsUnicode<'a>(&'a Fraction);
    impl<'a> std::fmt::Display for FractionAsUnicode<'a> {
        fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
            write!(f, "{}⁄{}", self.0.numerator, self.0.denominator)
        }
    }
    FractionAsUnicode(self)
}
```

Here we declared the returned "hidden" object with a lifetime `'a` (being the lifetime of the original `Fraction` reference given to the `unicode` function), which we must also spell out in the `impl` block. This is standard for structs with references. The slightly surprising thing is the extra `+ '_` added to the return type. Without this, the compiler complains: "hidden type for `impl std::fmt::Display` captures lifetime that does not appear in bounds". It is saying that, even though we don't actually spell out the lifetimes in the `unicode` signature, there *is* a connection between the lifetime of the returned instance and that of the original `Fraction` instance, namely, that the returned instance cannot outlive the original instance.

Short answers to the questions you pose in the comments:

- What about multiple functions or associated types, e.g. `-> impl Iterator<Item = i32>`? Since you have to have a full `impl` block for the trait, you can declare all the functions and the associated types as usual.
- Can I re-use `self`? No, as seen above, you need to capture a reference, clone the data, or extract some data you need into the returned instance.

Finally, let me point out that `-> impl SomeTrait` does *not* mean this function returns a trait object (as in `-> Box<dyn SomeTrait>`). The function cannot, for example, return *different* implementations of `SomeTrait` from different branches. The syntax simply means that there exists a single type that implements the trait, but you won't see which type that is from the signature.