error using AsRef<Path>: expected type parameter `P`, found `&Path`
I've been enjoying writing APIs that use AsRef<Path> for a parameter type since then that calling function doesn't have to worry about whether it has a str, String, PathBuf, Path or whatever, but in some new code I ran into a problem where a new function I wrote take two paths, and it seems like I can't use the same kind of flexibility, which is unexpected.
I created an isolated (contrived) example (see playground):
use anyhow;
use std::path::Path;

fn do_some_file_stuff<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P, path2: P) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
  println!("some file stuff, with path: {} and path2: {}", path.as_ref().display(), path2.as_ref().display());
  Ok(())
}

fn do_something<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P, path2: P) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
   do_some_file_stuff(path, path2)
}

fn do_another_thing<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
   let outdir = path.as_ref().parent().unwrap_or(Path::new("."));
   do_some_file_stuff(path, outdir)
}

fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
   let path_str = "data/myfile.txt";
   do_something(path_str, "data/another.txt")?;
   do_another_thing(path_str)?;
   println!("success");
   Ok(())
}


The full error output is:
 Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:16:29
   |
13 | fn do_another_thing<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
   |                     - expected this type parameter
...
16 |    do_some_file_stuff(path, outdir)
   |    ------------------ ----  ^^^^^^ expected type parameter `P`, found `&Path`
   |    |                  |
   |    |                  expected all arguments to be this type parameter `P` type because they need to match the type of this parameter
   |    arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `P`
                   found reference `&Path`
note: function defined here
  --> src/main.rs:4:4
   |
4  | fn do_some_file_stuff<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P, path2: P) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
   |    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -               -------  -------- this parameter needs to match the type parameter `P` type of `path`
   |                       |               |
   |                       |               `path2` needs to match the type parameter `P` type of this parameter
   |                       `path` and `path2` all reference this parameter P

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to 1 previous error


I'm confused since I understood that &Path conforms to P (AsRef<Path>), but in this case I'm seeing an error.  The error seems to be saying that the two function parameters need to be the same type, but I understood from reading a lot of different docs and articles that this syntax should mean they can be different types that each implement the same trait.
Can someone explain what the error message means and how to write the code so it compiles?
UPDATE (thx @kmdreko for the comment):
I can change the function signature to work as I intended by specifying two different type identifiers:
fn do_some_file_stuff<P1: AsRef<Path>, P2: AsRef<Path>>(path: P1, path2: P2) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
  println!("some file stuff, with path: {} and path2: {}", path.as_ref().display(), path2.as_ref().display());
  Ok(())
}

This doesn't make sense given my mental model of this syntax.  I learned about it by reading someone else's code and have been using it for a while, and can't find exactly where that would be explained.   It would be great to see an answer with a doc reference that explains this syntax +/or alternate sample code that uses something more idiomatic for Rust.

"... this syntax should mean they can be different types ..." - path and path2 have to be the same type since they are both use the same type parameter. Perhaps you had it confused with the path: impl AsRef<...> syntax?

@kmdreko I'm using the word "type" rather loosely.  I understood that the AsRef syntax means any type that implements that trait... not that once I pass a specific type it somehow binds that function to accept only that type.   I am having trouble finding where to look in the docs that explains this use case.  Appreciate any references that explains this pattern (or the pattern I'm attempting to use)

I gotcha. P is a generic type parameter, so it can be different between invocations. However within an invocation, P refers to a single type. So your parameters could be PathBuf, PathBuf or &str, &str, but not PathBuf, &str.

found some more info about using impl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47514930/what-are-the-differences-between-an-impl-trait-argument-and-generic-function-par ... which points to initial RFC arguing for the impl syntax which seems to have been added later

Using impl <trait> creates an "anonymous generic parameter" (see RFC detailed design)
Here's an alternate syntax using impl (see playground):
fn do_some_file_stuff(path: impl AsRef<Path>, path2: impl AsRef<Path>) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
  println!("some file stuff, with path: {} and path2: {}", path.as_ref().display(), path2.as_ref().display());
  Ok(())
}

