# How can a function require that a type implement a trait without removing the existing trait bound?

Tags: generics, struct, rust, traits, type-parameter

I'm trying to have a `main_func` that returns a vector of a type `T` structs with a `SrObject` trait

```
struct TestA {
    value: u8,
}

pub trait SrObject {
    fn myfunc(&mut self);
}
impl SrObject for TestA {
    fn myfunc(&mut self) {
        unimplemented!();
    }
}
impl Default for TestA {
    fn default() -> TestA {
        TestA { value: 3u8 }
    }
}

fn main_func<T: SrObject>(t: T) -> Vec<T> {
    let mut v = Vec::<T>::new();
    for i in 0..10 {
        v.push(T::default());
        //v[i].myfunc();
    }
    return v;
}
```

it gives:

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `default` found for type `T` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:22:16
   |
22 |         v.push(T::default());
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `T`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `default`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `std::default::Default`
```

I understand that I don't have the `Default` trait in fn `main_func<T: SrObject>`, but how can I achieve this without removing the `SrObject` trait?

Comment: You've asked enough questions that you should know to include the *entire* error message without me needing to edit it in for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd encourage you to go back and reread [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/). This is a free online book that the Rust community has created that covers a broad spectrum of the things you need to know to be a successful Rust programmer.

In this case, the [chapter on traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-02-traits.html) mentions this about [trait bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-02-traits.html#trait-bounds):

> We can specify multiple trait bounds on a generic type by using `+`. If we needed to be able to use display formatting on the type `T` in a function as well as the `summary` method, we can use the trait bounds `T: Summarizable + Display`. This means `T` can be any type that implements both `Summarizable` and `Display`.

For your case:

```
fn main_func<T: SrObject + Default>() -> Vec<T> {
    (0..10).map(|_| T::default()).collect()
}
```

Or

```
fn main_func<T>() -> Vec<T>
where
    T: SrObject + Default,
{
    (0..10).map(|_| T::default()).collect()
}
```

Other changes to make it idiomatic:

- Don't specify the type of `v` when calling `Vec::new`; it will be inferred.
- Don't use an explicit `return` at the end of a function.
- Use [`Iterator::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) and [`Iterator::collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) to convert the iterator into a collection, instead of pushing elements by hand.

See also:

- [Difference between <T: Trait> and where T: Trait](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46793494/155423)