# What makes `impl Trait` as an argument "universal" and as a return value "existential"?

Tags: rust, universal, existential-type

I was reading the [RFC on "expanding" impl Trait](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1951-expand-impl-trait.md) when I came upon the following:

> By contrast, a programmer who first learned: `fn take_iter(t: impl
>   Iterator)` and then tried: `fn give_iter() -> impl Iterator` would be
>   successful, without any rigorous understanding that they just
>   transitioned from a universal to an existential.

While I understand universal vs existential from a logic perspective, what makes the first one above universal and the second one existential?

Comment: It was chosen to work this way because these are the most common use cases. There are also cases where an existential argument type or a universal return type would be useful, but these are relatively rare so the RFC chose not to implement them and keep things simple.

Comment: @interjay A common example of a universally quantified return type is `Into::into()`. The caller supplies the type that they want to get back (usually by inference).

Answer (score 15):

The RFC defines the terms multiple times in multiple manners:

> between existential types (where the callee chooses the type) and universal types (where the caller chooses)

> There's been a lot of discussion around universals vs. existentials (in today's Rust, generics vs impl Trait).

> - Universal quantification, i.e. "for any type T", i.e. "caller
>     chooses". This is how generics work today. When you write
>     `fn foo<T>(t: T)`, you're saying that the function will work for any
>     choice of `T`, and leaving it to your caller to choose the `T`.
> - Existential quantification, i.e. "for some type T", i.e. "callee
>     chooses". This is how `impl Trait` works today (which is in return
>     position only). When you write `fn foo() -> impl Iterator`, you're
>     saying that the function will produce some type `T` that implements
>     `Iterator`, but the caller is not allowed to assume anything else
>     about that type.

TL;DR:

- `fn take_iter(t: impl Iterator)` — the person calling `take_iter` picks the concrete type. The function has to work for the entire "universe" of types that implement the trait.
- `fn give_iter() -> impl Iterator` — the implementation of `give_iter` picks the concrete type. There is some type which "exists" and implements the trait that will be returned by the function.