# Can you use impl Fn to accept arbitrarily-sized closures as arguments?

Tags: rust, closures

I have a `History` type which contains an initial state, a current state, and a list of closures with every change required to compute the current state from the initial state. These are applied with an `.apply(...)` method which takes a boxed closure, uses it to modify the current state, and adds it to the list. Because I want these to be deterministically reusable they are `Fn`, not `FnMut` or `FnOnce`.

```
struct History<State: Clone> {
    initial: State,
    current: State,
    updates: Vec<Box<dyn Fn(&mut State)>>,
}

impl<State: Clone> History<State> {
    fn apply(&mut self, update: Box<dyn Fn(&mut State)>) {
        update(&mut self.current);
        self.updates.push(update);
    }
}
```

I am currently taking closures as `Box<dyn Fn(&mut State)>`, and it works fine:

```
fn main() {
    let mut history = History::<usize> {
        initial: 0,
        current: 0,
        updates: vec![],
    };

    let delta = 10;
    history.apply(Box::new(move |mut value| *value += delta));

    println!("{}", history.current);
}
```

```
10
```

This got me thinking about whether it would be possible for a method to accept arbitrary *unboxed* closures by using `impl Trait` instead of `dyn Trait`. In this case, our method could box the closures itself, so the call site would become:

```
    history.apply(move |mut value| *value += delta);
```

*(Please entertain the question of whether this is even possible, even if it's a bad idea in this case.)*

I am imagining that each closure site is like a distinct data type, instantiated with the enclosed values each time it's used, so `impl` Trait could specialize the method for each implicit closure like it does for each explicit type. But I'm not sure whether Rust actually works like that.

However, when I try making the change in the code, I get a new lifetime error:

```
    fn apply(&mut self, update: impl Fn(&mut State)) {
        update(&mut self.current);
        self.updates.push(Box::new(update));
    }
```

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `impl Fn(&mut State)` may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:10:27
   |
10 |         self.updates.push(Box::new(update));
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: ...so that the type `impl Fn(&mut State)` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/main.rs:10:27
   |
10 |         self.updates.push(Box::new(update));
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This confuses me. I'm not sure where there's a reference that could be going bad.

In my head, the entire closure state is now being moved into `apply` via the `impl Fn` parameter, then moved into a `Box` that is owned by `self`. But it's complaining that I can't move the contents to a box, because I have a potentially-stale reference, not just owned data? Where am I borrowing anything? Why didn't this occur when I boxed the closure directly in `main` instead of in `apply`?

---

Is it possible to use `impl Fn` to accept an (arbitrarily-sized) closure as an argument? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you use impl Fn to accept arbitrarily-sized closures as arguments?

Yes.

`impl trait` in argument position is the exact same as a generic. These are identical:

```
fn foo1(_: impl Fn(u8) -> i8) {}
```

```
fn foo2<F>(_: F)
where
    F: Fn(u8) -> i8,
{}
```

This is in fact the *generally preferred* way to accept a closure (or many other trait implementations) because it allows the compiler to *monomorphize* the result and avoids any unneeded indirection.

---

Compiling your code has this help text ([which currently has some rendering glitches](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50817)):

```
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `impl Fn(&mut State): 'static`...
   |
8  |     fn apply(&mut self, update: impl Fn(&mut State): 'static +  {
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What it means to say is to add `+ 'static`:

```
fn apply(&mut self, update: impl Fn(&mut State) + 'static)
```

This works.

See also:

- [What makes `impl Trait` as an argument "universal" and as a return value "existential"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47929824/155423)
- [Why is adding a lifetime to a trait with the plus operator (Iterator<Item = &Foo> + 'a) needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42028470/155423)
- [The compiler suggests I add a 'static lifetime because the parameter type may not live long enough, but I don't think that's what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40053550/155423)

Comment: Thanks Shep. The point that most caught me was that I thought adding `'static` meant I was somehow declaring that my data must live forever, but after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40053649/1114) you linked, it finally clicked that I'm just saying that my data can't have any references that aren't themselves `'static`, which does make sense (I don't intend for it to have *any* references).