# Is it possible to assign a closure to a variable of type impl Fn()?

Tags: types, rust, closures

I was able to make this code work:

```
fn twice<T: Clone>(fst: impl Fn(T), snd: impl Fn(T)) -> impl Fn(T) {
    move |t| {
        fst(t.clone());
        snd(t)
    }
}
```

However, what I want is this (without boxing):

```
fn sub<T: Clone>(mut fst: impl Fn(T), snd: impl Fn(T)) {
    fst = move |t: T| {
        fst(t.clone());
        snd(t)
    };
}
```

Is there a way I can make the second piece of code work without boxing, using traits, type casting or any other method? Rust complains that the types do not match.

Comment: At first your approach is wrong, you are moving `fst` into `sub` function then trying to change it's value. but returning nothing ? `fst` is going to be dropped inside sub function.

Answer (score 5):

This cannot be done without boxing. The reason is that the actual type of `fst` in the input is different than the type of the closure that you later overwrite it with. The only way to make them the same type is with a trait object.

The boxed version might look like this:

```
use std::mem;

fn sub<'a, T: Clone + 'a>(fst: &mut Box<dyn Fn(T) + 'a>, snd: impl Fn(T) + 'a) {
    // Replace the original fst with a dummy closure while the new closure is being
    // constructed, to avoid the reference being temporarily invalid
    let fst_orig = mem::replace(fst, Box::new(|_| {}));
    *fst = Box::new(move |t: T| {
        fst_orig(t.clone());
        snd(t)
    });
}


fn main() {
    let mut f1: Box<dyn Fn(i32)> = Box::new(|x| println!("f1: {}", x));
    let f2 = |x| println!("f2: {}", x);

    sub(&mut f1, f2);

    f1(42);
}
```

But I really am not sure why you would want to do this!

Comment: And also this simple [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7d29a34ebe5a0cd6366da331463cae31) , check the error, it says: "note: no two closures, even if identical, have the same type", "help: consider boxing your closure and/or using it as a trait object"

Comment: *But I really am not sure why you would want to do this!* — This 100%. Just [reassign `fst` and let it get a new type](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=11c373e10f2b0f9a1b95867f2d0488f4).

Comment: @Shepmaster I actually made an assumption that OP wanted to overwrite the input fn pointer, which wasn't quite expressed in the question. That's why I included an example `main` that uses the solution. If it was just a matter of reusing the variable name _inside_ the function, it seemed too trivial a request - but maybe that's what OP actually wanted?

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question you *asked*,  no, you cannot yet assign a closure to a variable with the type `impl Fn` because you cannot yet declare such a variable:

```
fn foo() {
    let x: impl Fn() = move || println!("Hello");
}
```

```
error[E0562]: `impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and inherent method return types
 --> src/lib.rs:2:12
  |
2 |     let x: impl Fn() = move || println!("Hello");
  |            ^^^^^^^^^
```

"But wait!" you say, "I have such a type in my function argument!". Truth is that no, you do not.

This syntax:

```
fn foo(x: impl Fn()) {}
```

Is just shorthand for this:

```
fn foo<F>(x: F)
where
    F: Fn(),
{}
```

You've simply constructed a generic and applied a trait bound to it.

See also:

- [What makes `impl Trait` as an argument "universal" and as a return value "existential"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47929824/155423)