# Is there a shorter way of writing function signatures that take and return closures?

Tags: rust

Is there a shorter way of writing these function signatures?

```rust
fn hof_five(a: i32, func: impl Fn(i32) -> i32) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 {
    move |v| func(a + v)
}

fn hof_six(a: i32, func: Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32>) -> Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32> {
    Box::new(move |v| func(a + v))
}
```

Something like using `F: impl Fn(i32) -> i32 or F: Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32>`

So that the signature becomes something like:

```rust
fn hof_five<F>(a: i32, func: F) -> F {
    move |v| func(a + v)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to create a type alias for multiple traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070559/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-type-alias-for-multiple-traits)

Comment: [Example using duplicate answer's](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c035780d7022949db46f36422970f2dd)

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks. This trait Func = Fn(i32) -> i32; helps. Thanks for the link also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two examples you gave are quite different.

```
fn hof_five(a: i32, func: impl Fn(i32) -> i32) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 {
    move |v| func(a + v)
}
```

This function accepts a closure of a type implementing `Fn(i32) -> i32`, and returns a closure of a type implementing this trait, but the argument and return types are different types. The argument type is inferred by the compiler based on the closure you pass in, and the return type is inferred based on the closure you return. Each closure has its own individual type.

Since argument type and return type are different types, there is no way to refer to them by the same name. The only thing you could do is define a trait that requires `Fn(i32) -> i32` as a prerequisite:

```
trait MyFn: Fn(i32) -> i32 {}

impl<T> MyFn for T
where
    T: Fn(i32) -> i32,
{}
```

With this trait definition, you can rewrite `hof_five` as

```
fn hof_five(a: i32, func: impl MyFn) -> impl MyFn {
    move |v| func(a + v)
}
```

The blanket implementation of `MyFn` makes sure that all closures implementing `Fn(i32) -> i32` automatically also implement `MyFn`.

```
fn hof_six(a: i32, func: Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32>) -> Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32> {
    Box::new(move |v| func(a + v))
}
```

This function accepts a *pointer* pointing to a closure implementing `Fn(i32) -> i32`, but the concrete type of that closure is not known at compile time. If you actually call the closure, the concrete type of the closure is determined at runtime, and the generated code dynamically dispatches to the right function. In this case, argument type and return type are the same type, so you can use a type alias if you want to:

```
type MyBoxedFn = Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32>;

fn hof_six(a: i32, func: MyBoxedFn) -> MyBoxedFn {
    Box::new(move |v| func(a + v))
}
```

This is completely equivalent to the original version.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Using the trait MyFn, the boxed one can also be written like: fn hof_six_trait(a: i32, func: Box<dyn MyFn>) -> Box<dyn MyFn> { Box::new(move |v| func(a + v)) }. This also works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not usefully, no, there is not.

To make something shorter, you generally have to reduce redundancy or remove characters.

- There's no *semantic* redundancy because the argument and return type mean different things.
- `impl` and `fn` and `i32` are already abbreviated, so they can't have characters removed.

All that's left is textual similarities. You *can* use a macro to do that, but **I don't think it's a good idea**:

```
macro_rules! F {
    () => (impl Fn(i32) -> i32);
}

fn hof_five(a: i32, func: F!()) -> F!() {
    move |v| func(a + v)
}
```

See also:

- [What makes `impl Trait` as an argument "universal" and as a return value "existential"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47929824/155423)

---

You might also be interested in using `where` clauses to spread out the complexity:

```
fn hof_five<F>(a: i32, func: F) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32
where
    F: Fn(i32) -> i32,
{
    move |v| func(a + v)
}
```