# How to implement a multi-level currying function in Rust?

Tags: function, rust, functional-programming, closures, currying

I attempt to implement a currying function similar to [Functional Programming Jargon in Rust](https://functional.works-hub.com/learn/functional-programming-jargon-in-rust-1b555#currying):

```rust
fn add_origin(x: i32) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 {
    return move |y| {
        x + y
    };
}

fn main() {
    let add5 = add_origin(5);
    println!("Call closure: {}", add5(6));
}
```

This works, but if I add one level deeper:

```rust
fn add(x: i32) -> impl Fn(i32) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 {
    return move |y: i32| {
        return move |z: i32| {
            x + y + z
        }
    };
}

fn main() {
    let add5 = add(5);
    let add5_10 = add5(10);
    println!("Call closure: {}", add5_10(6));
}
```

Compiler does not accept and tells me:

```
error[E0562]: `impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and inherent method return types
 --> src/main.rs:7:35
  |
7 | fn add(x: i32) -> impl Fn(i32) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 {
  |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Why is this not allowed? Is there a better alternative in Rust?

Comment: I found a solution: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=815b9f37a959632e0ce942944d047f04

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`impl Trait` syntax can only be used in argument position or return position of a function signature. Both of these are fine:

```rust
fn takes_fn(fn_arg: impl Fn(i32) -> i32) {}

fn returns_fn() -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 {
  |x| x
}
```

However neither of these work:

```rust
fn takes_fn(fn_arg: impl Fn(i32) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32) {}

fn returns_fn() -> impl Fn(i32) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 {
  |x| x
}
```

Because the second nested `impl Trait` is no longer in argument or return position but is now part of the argument or return type's signature, which is not somewhere where it is allowed. Basically, multiple nested `impl Trait`s will never work regardless of where you place them and you'll always get the same compile error.

The good news is this doesn't stop you from accomplishing what you want to accomplish because `impl Trait` is just syntax sugar and its use is optional. In your particular example we can use a boxed trait object to return your curried function.

```rust
fn add(x: i32) -> impl Fn(i32) -> Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32> {
    move |y: i32| {
        Box::new(move |z: i32| {
            x + y + z
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let add5 = add(5);
    let add5_10 = add5(10);
    println!("Call closure: {}", add5_10(6)); // prints "Call closure: 21"
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=815b9f37a959632e0ce942944d047f04)

See also:

- [What does `impl` mean when used as the argument type or return type of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48545035/2766908)
- [What makes `impl Trait` as an argument "universal" and as a return value "existential"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47929824/2766908)