# Rust generic type on closure

Tags: generics, rust

I would like to make a generic structure with closures, trying to model the finite state machine with Rust. A finite state machine holds two mappings(closures in this case);

- update: input X state => state
- output: input X state => output

Here is my first attempt.

```rust
pub struct Fsm<A, S, B, U, O>
where
    A: Clone,
    S: Clone,
    B: Clone,
    U: Fn(&A, &S) -> S + Clone,
    O: Fn(&A, &S) -> B + Clone,
{
    update: U,
    output: O,
    state: S,
    _a: PhantomData<A>,
    _b: PhantomData<B>,
}

impl<A, S, B, U, O> Fsm<A, S, B, U, O>
where
    A: Clone,
    S: Clone,
    B: Clone,
    U: Fn(&A, &S) -> S + Clone,
    O: Fn(&A, &S) -> B + Clone,
{
    pub fn new(update: U, output: O, state: S) -> Self {
        Fsm {
            update: update,
            output: output,
            state: state,
            _a: PhantomData,
            _b: PhantomData,
        }
    }

    pub fn get_state(&self) -> S {
        self.state.clone()
    }

    fn put_state(&mut self, state: &S) -> () {
        self.state = state.to_owned();
    }

    pub fn react(&mut self, input: &A) -> B {
        let new_state = (self.update)(input, &self.get_state());
        self.put_state(&new_state);
        (self.output)(input, &new_state)
    }
}

impl<A, S1, B, U1, O1> Fsm<A, S1, B, U1, O1>
where
    A: Clone,
    S1: Clone,
    B: Clone,
    U1: Fn(&A, &S1) -> S1 + Clone,
    O1: Fn(&A, &S1) -> B + Clone,
{
    pub fn product<C, S2, U2, U3, O2, O3>(
        self,
        fsm: Fsm<B, S2, C, U2, O2>,
    ) -> Fsm<A, (S1, S2), C, U3, O3>
    where
        S2: Clone,
        C: Clone,
        U2: Fn(&B, &S2) -> S2 + Clone,
        U3: Fn(&A, &(S1, S2)) -> (S1, S2) + Clone,
        O2: Fn(&B, &S2) -> C + Clone,
        O3: Fn(&A, &(S1, S2)) -> C + Clone,
    {
        Fsm::new(
            |x, (s1, s2)| {
                let new_s1 = (self.update)(x, s1);
                (new_s1, (fsm.update)(&(self.output)(x, &new_s1), s2))
            },
            |x, (s1, s2)| {
                let new_s1 = (self.update)(x, s1);
                let new_s2 = (fsm.update)(&(self.output)(x, &new_s1), s2);
                (fsm.output)(&(self.output)(x, &new_s1), &new_s2)
            },
            (self.state, fsm.state),
        )
    }
}
```

However, it has two annoying parts;

1. If one does not put `_a`, and `_b` compiler complains. `A, B` are there to relate the `U` and `O`.
2. the product part make compile error like following;

```
arguments to this function are incorrect
expected type parameter `U3`
          found closure `[closure@src/lib.rs:104:13: 104:26]`
every closure has a distinct type and so could not always match the caller-chosen type of parameter `U3`
expected type parameter `O3`
          found closure `[closure@src/lib.rs:108:13: 108:26]`
every closure has a distinct type and so could not always match the caller-chosen type of parameter `O3`rustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
```

How could I resolve these issues?

Comment: nit: It's uncommon to add type restrictions on the `struct` definition itself, you have to repeat them for the `impl` anyways and it just makes the type less general.

Comment: Nitpicks: `to_owned()` -> `clone()`, also you can use one `PhantomData<(A, B)>` and prefer `PhantomData<fn() -> T>` to `PhantomData<T>` because it doesn't inherit auto traits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first concern can be easily solved by just using the constructor you defined `Fsm::new` where you want to create a new instance and if you want to pattern match you can use something like `Fsm{ update, ..}` as pattern and ignore everything not specified. Also with the bound `O: Fn(&A, &S) -> B + Clone` on the struct `_b` is just not needed at all.

The first set of errors can be overcome by using [existential types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929824/what-makes-impl-trait-as-an-argument-universal-and-as-a-return-value-existe) instead of universal generics for `U3` and `O3`:

```rust
pub fn product<C, S2, U2, O2>(
    self,
    fsm: Fsm<B, S2, C, U2, O2>,
) -> Fsm<
    A,
    (S1, S2),
    C,
    impl Fn(&A, &(S1, S2)) -> (S1, S2) + Clone,
    impl Fn(&A, &(S1, S2)) -> C + Clone,
>
where
    S2: Clone,
    C: Clone,
    U2: Fn(&B, &S2) -> S2 + Clone,
    O2: Fn(&B, &S2) -> C + Clone,
{
    /*...*/
}
```

But now you get a bunch of borrow checker errors.

You can resolve most of them by requiring `'static` closures for your types. If that's not flexible enough you'd have to replace `'static` with appropriate named lifetimes everywhere in the snippet below.
The rest can be resolved by adding `clone` and `move` so we create necessary copies of the `Fn` arguments and move them.

```rust
impl<A, S1, B, U1, O1> Fsm<A, S1, B, U1, O1>
where
    A: Clone,
    S1: Clone,
    B: Clone,
    U1: Fn(&A, &S1) -> S1 + Clone + 'static,
    O1: Fn(&A, &S1) -> B + Clone + 'static,
{
    pub fn product<C, S2, U2, O2>(
        self,
        fsm: Fsm<B, S2, C, U2, O2>,
    ) -> Fsm<
        A,
        (S1, S2),
        C,
        impl Fn(&A, &(S1, S2)) -> (S1, S2) + Clone,
        impl Fn(&A, &(S1, S2)) -> C + Clone,
    >
    where
        S2: Clone,
        C: Clone,
        U2: Fn(&B, &S2) -> S2 + Clone + 'static,
        O2: Fn(&B, &S2) -> C + Clone + 'static,
    {
        Fsm::new(
            {
                let self_update = self.update.clone();
                let fsm_update = fsm.update.clone();
                let self_output = self.output.clone();
                move |x, (s1, s2)| {
                    let new_s1 = (self_update)(x, s1);
                    (new_s1.clone(), (fsm_update)(&(self_output)(x, &new_s1), s2))
                }
            },
            move |x, (s1, s2)| {
                let new_s1 = (self.update)(x, s1);
                let new_s2 = (fsm.update)(&(self.output)(x, &new_s1), s2);
                (fsm.output)(&(self.output)(x, &new_s1), &new_s2)
            },
            (self.state, fsm.state),
        )
    }
}
```