# What's the type of an async fn?

Tags: types, async-await, rust, future

I want to have a function that takes a [function pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-05-advanced-functions-and-closures.html) of `async fn`.
What should the type of `f` be in `fn run`?

```
async fn foo() {}

fn run(f: /* ??? */) {}
```

According to the [async/await RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2394-async_await.md):

> An `async fn foo(args..) -> T` is a function of the type `fn(args..) -> impl Future<Output = T>`.

However, if I write

```
fn run(f: fn() -> impl Future<()>)
```

I get the error message:

```
`impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and inherent method return types
```

Comment: There is an [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50547) going on for the async/await

Comment: @hellow I updated my question and I think mine is quite different from the one you suggested.

Comment: Okay, I can accept that, thanks for editing your question :)

Comment: Maybe this is a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577070/how-to-use-fn-traits-closures-in-signatures-in-rust

Answer (score 3):

You have to introduce two type parameters to your function signature, one for the `Fn` and one for the `Future`, e.g.

```
#![feature(futures_api, async_await)]

async fn foo() {}

fn run<G: std::future::Future, F: FnOnce() -> G>(f: F) {
    f();
}

fn main() {
    bar(foo)
}
```

You can replace `FnOnce` with `Fn` or `FnMut` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Using generic type parameter can help since an `async fn` returns an implementation of the `Future` trait.

```
#![feature(futures_api, async_await)]

use std::future::Future;

fn main() {
    run(foo);
}

async fn foo() {}

fn run<T: Future>(f: fn() -> T) {
    f();
}
```